# Can Visual Studio Code point Python Interpreter to the Embedded Version?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After installed Microsoft Visual Studio, I got python 3.6.3, which later can be seen in Visual Studio Code, by command "Python: Select Interpreter".

Also, I downloaded [Python 3.7.3 embed-amd64 version](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/) and extracted it to `C:\python-3.7.3-embed-amd64`, inside where there is a `python.exe` that can be run directly.

Now, is it possible to config Visual Studio Code, so that python 3.7.3 will be an option visible?

Comment: did you try adding the path of the python executable in select python interpreter ? you could know the path by command: whereis python

Comment: @AmartyaGaur how to add the path?

Comment: Just paste it in the search bar sorts that appears when you click on select python interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the path to the python executable:

you can find the path by : `whereis python` command

paste it in the bar where current is written

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) then yes. However, I strongly recommend you to create virtualenv in your workdir using python 3.7.3 that you downloaded.